# Angular Dropdown-Select works outside <app-root> but not withiin?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-select

I have [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) working on my Angular App on the index.html.

But as soon as I move the dropdown from the index into a component within the `<app-root></app-root>` it stops working?

By that I mean the js does not render the new dropdown as it should?

Comment: Mixing jQuery with angular is always a bad idea. There are packages that implement bootstrap specific tailored for angular.

Comment: I have a similar problem; I have been trying to find a multiselect-dropdown that supports option groups.  bootstrap-select seemed to provide the answer but turns out to be very hard to use.

Comment: @penleychan, but Bootstrap 4 uses jQuery and that is used in many angular projects - we are using Black Dashboard PRO Angular (https://www.creative-tim.com/product/black-dashboard-pro-angular) and it works with jQuery?